# How may I select NCORE and NPAR in VASP?

Tags: vasp

I am using VASP/5.4.4, one node is equal to 40 core. So for calculations, I used 3 nodes, what should be the NCORE and NPAR for INCAR file?

Comment: Please refer to a previous answer of similar question: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4529/1554, VASP wiki has well documentation for the values of NCORE and NPAR as well: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NPAR

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallelization in VASP](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/parallelization-in-vasp)

Comment: @JaafarMehrez The question to which you provided a link, and the question to which Tristan provided a link, both do not have answers that mention NPAR. Also, the VASP Wiki is not hosted or maintained by us, so we have no control over whether or not it will still be online tomorrow or next year or next decade. **If you  can write an answer here** it will have the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, and even if Stack Exchange shuts down the answer will likely be available through archives. When people search for an answer about NPAR, this thread on SE might even appear earlier in the search results than VASP.

Answer (score 4):

This question has appeared so many times among VASP users either on ResearchGate [1](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_optimize_parallelization_in_VASP),[2](https://www.researchgate.net/post/NCORE-and-NPAR-in-VASP), or [VASP forum](https://wwww.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13310)  but it seems that there still exist some difficulties in making the right choice for setting up the parallelization parameters. I have to mention that some good answers could be found in the mentioned links. Moreover, a good starting point is the answer [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4529/1554), one practical benchmarking approach in the comments is also suggested [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/parallelization-in-vasp) by Tristan Maxson. Thus, I will try to combine what I have experienced on my own and answers I have come across from other users. For clarification, I am using VASP 5.4 and to my knowledge only MPI parallelization is used in this version, so when I use the term “core”, I mean the number of MPI ranks or processes, for example the number you give to the mpirun command using the -n command line flag or the number of cores you request in the queue system.

Now let's start with numer of cores, you will hear alot of people stating that you need to do your testing for the number of cores (which is True), but as a good start you can set `number of cores = number of atoms`. VASP has three levels of parallelization: over k-points, over bands, and over plane-wave coefficients or equivalently Fast-Fourier transforms. You have to make sure that when the work is split up among several computing nodes, there is a sufficient amount of work allocated to each processor core, otherwise, they will just spend time waiting for more work to arrive. Therefore, the fundamental numbers to be aware of are:

- The number of bands
- The number of k-points
- The size of the basis set

**NPAR & NBANDS:**

I will first address `NPAR` and `NBANDS` as they are correlated. VASP has parallelization over bands (controlled via the `NPAR` tag), where the default (NPAR=number of MPI ranks or cores). If you are not explicitly setting those two tags in your inputs, VASP will try to make sure that there is an equal number of bands on each node, when parallelizing over bands. Thus, one can unknowingly perform calculations with different number of bands when changing the number of cores in the job script. So, you have to set NPAR and NBANDS in the INCAR file. Alternatively, make sure that you have converged your calculation with respect to the number of bands. VASP guesses the number bands with quite a large safety margin, but it is not always enough!

Suppose you have 100 bands, you cannot run on more than 100 cores and expect it to work well. However, 1 band per core is very little work for a today's processor. You may need at least 2 bands per core to reach more than 50% efficiency. Then a better choice is 8 bands/core which will put you closer to 90% efficiency. So try to achieve the following `number of cores = NBANDS / 8`. For example, if you have a cell with 500 bands and a cluster with compute nodes having 16 cores per node. We aim for 8 bands/core, which unfortunately means 62.5 cores. It is better to have **even numbers**, so we increase the number of bands to 512 by setting `NBANDS=512` in the INCAR file and allocate 64 cores, or 4 nodes.

Now for `NPAR`, VASP wiki recommendation is  to set `NPAR = square root of (number of processor cores)`, keep that recommendation in mind but you should also know that the achitecture of the processors or clusters will have an influence in here as it has to do with how the nodes communicate with each other. In some cases, `NPAR = number of compute nodes / 2` and in other cases `NPAR = number of compute nodes`, you may find that by yourself, depending on the cluster you are using.

**KPAR:**

KPAR controls the number of k-point groups that run in parallel. The upper limit of KPAR is obviously the number of k-points in your calculation. In practice, k-point parallelization does not scale that well. So set `KPAR=compute nodes`. Regardless of the actual value of KPAR, it is **not** recommended to run with `KPAR>compute nodes`, even though you may have more k-points than compute nodes. For instance, take the 500 bands mentioned before. 64 cores was a good choice when using just band parallelization, suppose you have 8 k-points. Then set KPAR to 8 and double the number of cores to 128 cores (or 8 nodes). In this case, you have 1 k-point per node, which is a very balanced setup. In cases where run out of memory lower down KPAR to 4 or 2.

**NGZ:**

By default, VASP works with the FFTs in a plane-wise manner (`LPLANE=.TRUE.`). In the ideal case , you want NGZ (the number of grid points in the Z direction) to be evenly divisible by NPAR. That will ensure good load-balance (`NGZ=n*NPAR`). According to VASP wiki you should also consider that NGZ should be sufficiently big for the LPLANE approach to work, thus, (`NGZ ≥ 3*(number of cores)/NPAR = 3*NCORE`)

**Quick Solution:**

- start with (NBANDS). The number of bands divided by 8
  is a good starting guess for the number of cores to use for your
  calculation.
- set NPAR = number of compute nodes / 2 or in some cases NPAR = number
  of compute nodes, depending on the architecture of your processor.
- set KPAR to the number of compute nodes or the number of k-points, whichever is the smallest number. Then double the amount of cores determined in the previous step.
- Make a test run and check the value of NGZ, it should be an even
  number and sufficiently big (larger than 3*cores/node).

Comment: +1. When saying that the question has come up many times before, it would be helpful if you could provide links to those questions: this could make your answer a "hub" for information on the topic, but it also backs-up your claim. I understand that questions on the VASP forum might not be visible to people without a license,  but it would be helpful if you can provide as many links as you can.

Comment: @NikeDattani, Updated! Thanks for the suggestion.